# Angular form validation $pristine not working properly

Tags: angularjs

Can anyone tell me why my validation is being ignored?
Here is my form:

```
<form name="contactForm" role="form" ng-submit="controller.submit()" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : contactForm.fullName.$invalid && !contactForm.fullName.$pristine }">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fullName" placeholder="Full name" ng-model="controller.model.fullName" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : contactForm.email.$invalid && !contactForm.email.$pristine }">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address" ng-model="controller.model.email" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : contactForm.phoneNumber.$invalid && !contactForm.phoneNumber.$pristine }">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone number" ng-model="controller.model.phoneNumber" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : contactForm.orderQuantity.$invalid && !contactForm.orderQuantity.$pristine }">
        <select class="form-control" name="orderQuantity" ng-model="controller.model.orderQuantity">
            <option disabled selected>Order quantity</option>
            <option>10+</option>
            <option>20+</option>
            <option>30+</option>
            <option>40+</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : contactForm.country.$invalid && !contactForm.country.$pristine }">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country" ng-model="controller.model.country" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message" ng-model="controller.model.message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="recaptcha" theme="dark" vc-recaptcha key="'6Lcc0AgTAAAAAIpcEqqDI3Ko8dZ05H-GGgUnfOvA'"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I set up a codepen here:
http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/XbzyzQ?editors=101

Comment: which one it ignored ?

Comment: just a few corrections: for the email use `type="email"`instead of `type="text"` and for phone number consider using `type="tel"`

Comment: you could also disable the "Send" button as long as your form is pristine or invalid like this: `<button type='submit' data-ng-disabled='contactForm.$pristine || contactForm.$invalid'>Send/button>`

Comment: instead of using `!$pristine` you can use `$dirty` btw

Comment: Apart from some `required` attributes I don't see any validation btw

Answer (score 1):

you should check whether form is submitted or not using **contactForm.$submitted**.

After form submission  the **formController  object** is get updated and various parameter of each controll's model are get updated and then you can validate your data.

you have not checked this in your form validation.
The updated html is

```
<div class="container" ng-app="validationExample">
  <div class="row" ng-controller="ValidationController as controller">


    <form style="margin-top: 20px;" name="contactForm" role="form" ng-submit="controller.submit()" novalidate>
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' :  contactForm.fullName.$invalid && contactForm.$submitted }">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fullName" placeholder="Full name" ng-model="controller.model.fullName" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : contactForm.email.$invalid && contactForm.$submitted }">
        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address" ng-model="controller.model.email" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : contactForm.phoneNumber.$invalid   && contactForm.$submitted }">
        <input class="form-control" type="tel" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone number" ng-model="controller.model.phoneNumber" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : contactForm.$submitted && contactForm.orderQuantity.$invalid && contactForm.orderQuantity.$error.required }">
        <select class="form-control"  required name="orderQuantity" ng-model="controller.model.orderQuantity"> 
          <option disabled selected>Order quantity</option>
          <option>10+</option>
          <option>20+</option>
          <option>30+</option>
          <option>40+</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : contactForm.country.$invalid && contactForm.$submitted}">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country" ng-model="controller.model.country" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message" ng-model="controller.model.message"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the updated code [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXoJGe?editors=101)

Also instead of **$invalid** you can use  **required** to validate the fields.Also you can use regular expression to put your custom validation rule.

e.g.

```
   <input  name="first_name" class="form-control" required type="text" ng-model="NewUser.first_name"  ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z]+[0-9]*$/" />
                    <span ng-show="newuser.first_name.$error.pattern">This is not valid <b>Last name</b></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the validation is not ignored. In your `codepen` code, input whatever text and remove to empty. Then switch to another input element. The `has-error` class is added.

Because you are checking through `$dirty`, which is by default `false` if you do not alter any input text (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController):

> $dirty boolean
>   True if user has already interacted with the form.

I added `ng-minlength=5` to your code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGPmqR:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : contactForm.fullName.$invalid && contactForm.fullName.$dirty }">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fullName" placeholder="Full name" ng-model="controller.model.fullName" required ng-minlength=5 />
</div>
```

As you input any text, the `ng-minlength` rules is working.

Comment: Why write your own css when bootstrap has it built in?